# Prove that there is no computability reduction HP $\le$ $\Sigma$*

Tags: computability, reductions

I tried to prove in negative way that there is computability reduction  HP $\le$ $\Sigma$* and accept contradiction because of HP $\in$ RE and $\Sigma$* $\in$ R but it feels that is not strong argument.

There is a more solid way to prove it?

Comment: What is "HP"? Halting problem?

Comment: @dkaeae Yes, its Halting problem

Comment: I don't sure what you mean. I try to show there is no computable mapping from HP to $\Sigma$*

Comment: The argument is simple: To which string could you map the $\langle M_\bot, w \rangle$ when $M_\bot$ is a TM that never halts (i.e. a NO-instance for the halting problem)?

Comment: @ttnick As far as I'm aware "computability" reduction is not well-used terminology, but I'm certain the OP is talking about Turing, not many-one reductions.

Comment: @dkaeae Oh I see, I read "computability reduction" as "computable reduction".

Comment: What is a "computability reduction"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let us actually prove more: If $L$ is a language and $L \not\in \mathsf{R}$, then $L \not\le_\mathrm{T} L'$ for any $L' \in \mathsf{R}$. (Here, $\le_\mathrm{T}$ indicates a Turing reduction; this is synonymous with your notion of a "computability" reduction.) In other words, $\mathsf{R}$ is closed under Turing reductions.

Suppose towards a contradiction that such a reduction exists and is computed by a Turing machine $M$. Furthermore, let $M'$ be a decider for $L'$. Then there is a Turing machine which solves $L$, namely by directly simulating $M$, answering all of its oracle queries by simulating $M'$ on them, and, at the end, answering what $M$ does. This contradicts $L \not\in \textsf{R}$.

The case of the halting problem follows from it not being in $\mathsf{R}$ (since it is not even in $\mathsf{RE}$) and, naturally, $\Sigma^\ast \in \mathsf{R}$.

An aside: If you find the idea of classes closed under Turing reductions interesting, I suggest you look up the computation-theoretical notion of [Turing degree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_degree). $\mathsf{R}$ would be the "base case" (i.e., degree zero) in that context.